# ng-repeat current value used in onclick event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

My problem is pretty straightforward but I can't find an easy solution. I have a `ng-repeat` like this

```
<p ng-repeat="title in Menu.data[Menu.selected]">
    {{ title }}         
</p>
```

Now I need to ad an `onclick` event so I modified like this

```
<p ng-repeat="title in Menu.data[Menu.selected]" onclick="show({{ title }})">
    {{ title }}         
</p>
```

But the `onclick="show({{ title }})"` is not parsed by angular. Why?

---

EDIT: please note that `show` is a plain javascript function, not `$scope.show`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use ng-click, and since that is an Angular directive the attribute value is assumed to be an expression, so you don't have to use curly braces:

```
ng-click="show(title)"
```

If show is a global function, you can make sure it's available on the scope by simply writing:

```
$scope.show = show;
```

Comment: for a simple work, we must have to declare our js function inside anugular's scope. This is a real shit of Angular.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need the {{}}, try just using

`onclick="show(title)"`

However in angular you should be using the ng-click directive instead of onclick so a better approach would be:

`ng-click="show(title)"`

In both instances the curly braces aren't needed.

`show` would also need to be a function defined on `$scope` in your controller. For example:

`$scope.show = show;`

Comment: And with angular you should preferably use `ng-click`. I upvoted you but would like to see this change in your answer :)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, the output displayed in browser is this: `<p ng-repeat="title in Menu.data[Menu.selected]" ng-click="show(title)" class="ng-binding ng-scope">
 DMR spot model
</p>`

Comment: `show` is a plain javascript function, is not `$scope.show`

Comment: Then you can simply define it on the scope with `$scope.show = show;`

Comment: @Strille you are right... simple and fast (:
Can you edit your answer to this? It's the actual solution